# How to get attribute values if they are not equal to some values?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a xml like:

```
<movies>
    <movie name="aaa">
        ...
    </movie>
    <movie name="bbb">
        ...
    </movie>
    <movie name="ccc">
        ...
    </movie>
    <movie name="ddd">
        ...
    </movie>
    <movie name="eee">
        ...
    </movie>
</movies>
```

I would like to get the name of the movie if it is not 'aaa', or 'bbb', or 'ddd'. So I would like my output to be:

```
ccc
eee
```

Because I have several restrictions, I don't think it's suitable to use 'xsl:if'..I wrote my xslt like (I'm using xslt 1.0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="movies/movie/@name[not(self::aaa) and not(self::bbb) and not(self:ddd)]"/>
```

But the compiler complained there is a syntax error in this sentence..and I can't figure out why..

So could anybody help me with this? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this XPath expression:

```
movies/movie[@name!='aaa' and @name!='bbb' and @name!='ddd']/@name
```

or this one:

```
movies/movie/@name[.!='aaa' and .!='bbb' and .!='ddd']
```

the latter is shorter, but the former can be easily extended to check for other return not only the name, but the whole `<movie>` element - just remove `/@name` at the end. Or if you want that for the second, just add `/..` at the end.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The first solution worked. Actually I was also coming up with that one, but since I'm a newbie to xslt, I was wondering if the first xpath will make the selection slow?

Comment: @D.Q.: You are welcome :) If you really need *only* the `name` attribute, then the 2nd expression is the way to go. If you need the whole `<movie>`, then you *have to* use something like this: `<foreach select="movies/movie[@name!='aaa' and ...]">Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name"><br /> Description: <xsl:value-of select="descr"></xsl:for-each>`. Or even better: `<xsl:apply-templates select="movies/movie[@name!='aaa' and ...]" />`. I cannot help you further, since I do not know the structure of your XML, nor the expected result of your transformation.

Comment: I see your point :) and just one more question, if I have several more restrictions, e.g. the number of names that I need to exclude is somewhat large, like 8 or 10. Is there any other way that I can deal with it so that I won't have a very long xpath expression which is not that good for further extension...

Comment: Not really... If your selector is too complex (versus too long!), you may remove the name-restriction from it, use `<apply-templates>` and define two templates - "process"- and empty "ignore"-template. Like this: `<xsl:template select="movie" priority="1">..."process movie"...</template>` + `<xsl:template select="movie[@name='aaa' || @name='bbb' ...]" priority="2" />`. With XSLT 2.0 you could use the `index-of` function. But note that *it is all about syntax*. The core is: **the list of ignored movies is still inside your XSLT**, which is perhaps not good.

Comment: Alternatives would be: (+) Preprocess your input-XML to remove ignored movies *before* XSLT transformation (this is perhaps the best way). (+) Post-process your XSLT-output to filter-out ignored videos *after* transformation. (+) Generate the XSLT on-the fly, building you XPath-expression base on the information from the ignored-movies-database (this will degrade performance greatly if you batch-process XML files).

Answer (score 3):

**Consider using an expression like this, in case there are too-many values for comparison:**

```
/*/movie[not(contains('|aaa|bbb|ddd|', concat('|', @name, '|)))]/@name
```

This selects any `name` attribute of any `movie` element that is a child of the top element of the XSLT document, and whose value (of the `name` attribute) isn't one of the strings in the pipe-separated list of string values `"|aaa|bbb|ddd|"`.

Comment: @alex-shesterov, Thanks for catching this. Corrected now.

Comment: Thank you @DimitreNovatchev for providing this excellent solution!